# MySql Comma Separated Values , Fetch Using Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have to fetch the columns of table , in which one column values are separated by delimete comma, here is my table structure

```
id  | name | categoryID
 1    a       1,2,4
 2    b       333 , 1 , 5 , 54
 3    c       1114414 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7
 4    d       2 , 4 , 5, 333, 7 , 8

Here is my query

Select * from tableA where find_in_set ('categoryID' , '1,7,8,333');
```

But the above query is not working it returns empty rows.

Comment: You are searching for all those 4 values? Thats not `find_in_set`s job

Comment: why is you schema is in a strange way?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

I suggest you change your schema. A name is mapped to many categories

```
id,name,categoryId
1  a     1
2  a     2
3  a     4
4  b     1
5  b     5
```

Step 2:

Find all name of the following category

```
Select distinct name,id,category_id from tableA where categoryId IN (1,7,8,333);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tableA where find_in_set (categoryID , '1,7,8,333')
```

if you pass value 1 for categoryID, 'find_in_set' will return the value correctly.
But you are trying to pass (1,2,4), (333 , 1 , 5 , 54). Thus it return wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the find_in_set function is incorrect.
The following could be useful as it describes how to use the find_in_set function correctly.

Here you go: [find_in_set](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/find_in_set.php)

So, use it to find the position of a string in a comma separated list, like this(note that it is case insensitive):

```
select find_in_set('Z', 'a,b,z,0');
```

// will produce: 3

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OR in where as you are find_in_set wrongly.
use as

```
Select * from tableA where find_in_set ('1',categoryID) OR find_in_set ('7',categoryID);
```

don't enquote categoryID within single quote.